# reference-Request-IMO

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

I was thinking of participating in the Next years IMO(international mathematics Olympiad) and i wanted some book references to help me get to the Olympiad level .
The topics are : Algebra , Geometry , Combinatorics , and Number theory. 
I am currently a high school student with a very basic knowledge in number theory , some graphs and algorithms in combinatorics, and just high school algebra .
So,  if you will , bearing in mind my very basic level,  refer some books ( preferably 1 -the best in your opinion- in each topic)
Thanks.

Comment: i would use the book Problem solving strategies by Arthur Engel

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! , however i prefer some books specific in each topics.

Comment: this is an excellent book and we use it very often

Comment: You also have the IMO compendium, which is just a large collection of shortlist problems for the IMO over the ages. If nothing else, it will tell you more or less exactly what level the problems are, and give you a lot of practice using relevant techniques.

Comment: i think i should deeply understand the concepts and the theory behind it before trying to tackle problems ? or what do you think is the best strategy ?

Comment: I found the bibliography in the *Mathematical Olympiad Handbook* by Tony Gardiner very useful. You can read parts of it in Google Books: https://books.google.com/books?id=zyFLrAEVgv8C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA41&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Math_books

Try this links. Books which specific in every level according to the level.